# replacing text and deleting text using awk in file using

Tags: linux, sed, awk

I have a script and I want to do some replace and delete operations on it. I used `sed` to extract values between words `SendCommands` and `end` like this

```
sed -n '/SendCommands/,/end/p' ddtt
```

As `awk` was not giving me desired output so I'm sticking with this.
I pasted the output here just show how it looks like :[output](http://codepad.org/ITd5ly7A)  `sed` is giving the function and comment part.

How do I put multiple such occurrences in a file into an array and perform search and replace or delete one text/command at a time.

Like delete `access-list 4 permit 10.59.230.14;\` or `service timestamps debug datetime msec localtime show-timezone;\` etc
or replace `service timestamps debug datetime msec localtime show-timezone` or `service timestamps debug datetime msec localtime show-timezone`

INFO: SendCommands is actualy a function used in the script

Answer (score 1):

With `-f` for `sed` you can supply a script that contains the several commands.

In your case, this would be

`script.sed`

```
/SendCommands/,/end/p
```

And you can then

```
sed -f script.sed ddtt
```